# Laravel CLI fails to create new app due to Cannot use lexical variable $eventName as a parameter name

Tags: composer-php, laravel-5.4

After successful installation of Laravel's install tool using composer using `composer global require "laravel/installer"` command, the first attempt to create an application by running `laravel new app-name` fails with the following output, any advice will be appreciated :)

```
Crafting application...
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use lexical variable $eventName as a parameter name in /Users/ABN/.composer/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Event/Emitter.php on line 48
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /Users/ABN/.composer/vendor/laravel/installer/laravel:0
PHP   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /Users/ABN/.composer/vendor/laravel/installer/laravel:13
PHP   3. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() /Users/ABN/.composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:126
PHP   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() /Users/ABN/.composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:195
PHP   5. Laravel\Installer\Console\NewCommand->run() /Users/ABN/.composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:878
PHP   6. Laravel\Installer\Console\NewCommand->execute() /Users/ABN/.composer/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:259
PHP   7. Laravel\Installer\Console\NewCommand->download() /Users/ABN/.composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php:52
PHP   8. GuzzleHttp\Client->get() /Users/ABN/.composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php:125
PHP   9. GuzzleHttp\Client->createRequest() /Users/ABN/.composer/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php:125
PHP  10. GuzzleHttp\Client->getEmitter() /Users/ABN/.composer/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php:115
PHP  11. spl_autoload_call() /Users/ABN/.composer/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Event/HasEmitterTrait.php:15
PHP  12. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass() /Users/ABN/.composer/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Event/HasEmitterTrait.php:15
PHP  13. Composer\Autoload\includeFile() /Users/ABN/.composer/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:322
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Turned out the issue is related to the guzzle version installed on the system.

After seeing similar issue reported around guzzle 5.3 on some other repositories/apps, confirmed my globally installed version by running `composer global info guzzlehttp/guzzle` and it was 5.3. 
Then updating my composer's global installation by running `composer global update`solved the problem, after seeing the update report as shown bellow, running the same `laravel new app-name` generates the application successfully.

> Updating guzzlehttp/guzzle (5.3.0 => 6.2.3): Downloading (100%)

Answer (score 3):

This is related to Guzzle's PHP 7.x incompatibility and this has been [fixed](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/pull/1393) in Guzzle >=5.3.1.

The solution is to upgrade your Guzzle by modifying line in your `composer.json` file to:

```
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3.1",
```

or:

```
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3@stable",
```